# Some questions regarding synchronization objects [Linux os]

Tags: c, linux

I am very confused about following statements..

1. "Mutex is lightweight and faster than semaphore"
2. "Semaphore use more memory than condition variable"

I have read somewhere that semaphore is based on system calls ..and it deals more with scheduler so its slow than mutex. but i am not getting it. Please help me clearing these concepts.

Thanx

Comment: These statements are implementation-specific, but since you tagged your question linux that might be okay. However, since mutexes and semaphores don't serve the same purpose it doesn't make much sense to compare them directly. Also POSIX (and thus Linux) has 2 types of semaphores, one of which (SysV/XSI) is slow and depends on the kernel, and the other of which (POSIX) can be implemented in userspace with fallback to the kernel only when waiting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mutex and semaphore are two different things. Due to simplicity of a mutex it could be faster, but at the same time it serves a different purpose so comparing these two things is like comparing knife and riffle. Same goes for condition variables, they are just different. You can think of a semaphore as of mutex with conditions and a counter. Using those three objects you can implement the behavior of a semaphore. However, semaphores in POSIX can also be used to synchronize access to shared resources across processes, while mutex and condition are in-process only objects.

As for the lightweight and speed statements, I guess that depends on implementation. Semaphores in Linux are more complicated as they support inter-process synchronization, and mutex & condition are using `futex` subsystem with atomic operations. But again, comparing those things makes little to no sense as they serve different purposes.

I'd recommend you read the following on this subject:

- [Mutexes and Semaphores Demystified](http://www.netrino.com/node/202)
- [Mutex vs Semaphore. The toilet example](http://geekswithblogs.net/shahed/archive/2006/06/09/81268.aspx)
- [Monitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_%28synchronization%29), [Semaphore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_%28programming%29) and [Mutual exclusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion) wiki pages.

Comment: +1 but ... Not all systems are required to support this, but generally POSIX mutexes and condition variables may also be used between processes, if initialized properly. So it really boils down to the difference in the API's, which is really the most important as underlined by your first link.

Answer (score 0):

Note, you are not restricted to mutexes, semaphores, or condition variables.  You can also use straight up atomic operations. don't forget to Google "gcc atomic operations" too.  BTW they are the fastest/lowest level way you can synchronize.